# Email Validation MVC4 avoiding mail sites

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email

Im using VS2012, ASP MVC4.

I want validate the new registered user email using this on my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

This works, but I want block some email sites how: 10minutemail, etc.. I want searching a option that allows me config the DataType Email Anotation or extends it..

I thinks this can be more clean that a big regex that validate all.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can do it in your ViewModel's `Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)` method, but it requires a postback to perform the validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom email validation attribute that wraps over EmailAddressAttribute you are using now:

```
public class CustomEmailValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string[] blockedProviders = new[]
    {
        "10minutemail.com",
        "some-temporary-email.net"
    };

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var emailValidationAttribute = new EmailAddressAttribute();
        if (!emailValidationAttribute.IsValid(value))
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid email");
        bool isBlocked = blockedProviders.Any(pr => ((string)value)
            .EndsWith(pr, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (isBlocked)
            return new ValidationResult("Email provider is not allowed");
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Then you can mark email fields with `[CustomEmailValidation]` instead of `[EmailAddress]`.